# How does multiple axes work in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm currently working on highcharts and I am confused on how highcharts work with multiple axes, to be exact, i wanted to have a secondary axis-y but I don't understand how it works. Can someone explain to me how can I add the secondary axis and the data that i will be inputted on last will based on the secondary axis? Thank you.

Below is the example of multiple axes I've searched in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-multi-axes/

Below is the code of multiple axis:

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2]
            }
        },
        opposite: true

    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }

    }, { // Tertiary yAxis
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Sea-Level Pressure',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mb',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true
    }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too hard to explain by word so i've created sample chart with 2 y-Axis and i've comment on some important action to work with multiple yAxis.

HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

JS code

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Average Monthly Temperature and Rainfall in Tokyo'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        crosshair: true
    }],

    //Y-Axis is the line on a graph that runs vertically (up-down) through zero.
        //It is used as a reference line so you can measure from it.
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value}°C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        }
    }, { // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: 'Rainfall',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value} mm',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        ////////Notice: importance option
        opposite: true //This option will set position of this axis to the right side
    }],


    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'left',
        x: 120,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{ //Data for Secondary yAxis 
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        ////////Notice: importance option
        yAxis: 1, //This option will define which yAxis data will runs on, if not set default all data will runs on the 0 yAxis (as left side)
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        }

    }, { // Data for Primary yAxis
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        }
    }]
});
```

My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmtri1101/e4Lpdgj8/2/.

Hope it useful to you.

Comment: Ohh. this is exactly what i need! Thank youu.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have posted you have three y-axes. Highcharts gives these axis indexes 0, 1, 2 respectively. When you input a new series, you need to tell highcharts which axis this series should use, based on these indexes. So for example, to tie data to the *rainfall* axis, you will need to do the following:

```
series: {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [0,0.2,0.4]
}
```

See [API for information](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Cline%3E.yAxis) and the following [example from highcharts demos](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/yaxis/).